# React app-index.js:32 [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to ask for your assistance in understanding why the console is displaying this error during the login section.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfHYP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyT0N.png)

I have tried different paths and everything, but I couldn't figure out the error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Never post code as Image, please. Try to givevus a minimal reprodutible example.